# Django Querying Relation of Relation

Tags: django, orm, django-models, django-orm

I'm stuck on a Django ORM issue that is bugging me.  I have a set of models linked by a foreign key but the requirements are a bit odd.  I need to list items by their relation's relation.  This is hard to explain so I've tried to depict this below, given:

Work

- ManyToMany(Award)

Award

- ForeignKey(AwardCategory)

AwardCategory

I need to list work items so they are listed by the award category.  Desired output would be:

Work Instance A

- Award Instance A that belongs to Award Category Instance A
- Award Instance C that belongs to Award Category Instance A
- Award Instance G that belongs to Award Category Instance A

Work Instance A (same instance as above, but listed by different award__category)

- Award Instance F that belongs to Award Category Instance B
- Award Instance R that belongs to Award Category Instance B
- Award Instance Z that belongs to Award Category Instance B

Work Instance B

- Award Instance B that belongs to Award Category Instance A
- Award Instance A that belongs to Award Category Instance A

Essentially I want to list all work by the award category.  I can get this to work in part but my solution is filthy and gross.  I'm wondering if there is a better way.  I considered using a ManyToMany and a through attribute but I'm not certain if I'm utilizing it correctly.

Comment: Award.category points to 'Category', so what's 'AwardCategory'?

Comment: Your current desired output suggests that a Work instance can have multiple Awards but your model says only one Award.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the following as per your model's fields and relations:

```
for w in Work.objects.all():
    print w
    for award in w.award_set.order_by(awardcategory):
         print "%s that belongs to %s" % (award,award.awardcategory)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with a similar result but it still feels a little dirty :(

```
categories = AwardCategory.objects.all()
work = []
for cat in categories:
    work_in_cat = Work.objects.filter(awards__category=cat).distinct()
    for w in work_in_cat:
        work.append({
            'work': w,
            'category': cat,
            'awards': w.awards.filter(category=cat)
        })
```

This produces the results I want but it seems so wrong to be doing this in a for loop!